# Prevent unnecessary horizontal scrolling for child of a floated div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a floated `div` (`class='outer'`) of fixed height with dynamic content (`class='inner'`). The dimensions of the content are not known in advance. The width of the floated `div` must be flexible, but still have some maximal value:

```
<style>
.outer {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left
}
.inner {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red
}
</style>
<body>
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
<span>Text here</span>
</body>
```

This generally works; however, in case of excessive content height the following happens:

1. `.outer` assumes the width of the content, as it is below its `max-width`.
2. `.inner` is forced into `height` of the `.outer` and as a result the vertical scroll bar appears.
3. `.inner` is forced into a new constrained width, as the `.outer` will not resize once more to accommodate the scroll bar.
4. The completely unnecessary horizontal scroll bar appears as a result.

**The fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/w053kLkw/

Is there a way to prevent this mechanism of `overflow` and have both scroll bars appearing only when needed?

Comment: Have you tried `.outer {display:table;}` ?

Comment: @Roysh this seemingly overrides `height: 200px` and I do not get the desired vertical scrolling

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with some example content?

Comment: @Roysh I have posted the fiddle

Comment: try using `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`

https://jsfiddle.net/w053kLkw/2/

Comment: You can add an `overflow-x: hidden` to the outer and inner styles, this should do the trick (Not compatible with old IE).

Comment: @Roysh `display:inline-block` not only does not fix the problem, but in addition makes the element afterwards appear in the unwanted position.

Comment: @Roberto Lonardi: Sometimes the width of the content exceeds the `max-width` of `.outer` and in this case I need the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: is this what you're trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/w053kLkw/3/ ?

Comment: @Roysh No: 1) I need fixed example width of `.inner` (as in my case it is usually an image, which I do not want to resize); 2) Text must appear right to the box, not below

Comment: This https://jsfiddle.net/w053kLkw/6/ ?

Comment: @Roysh No, I need scrolling in case the content is bigger than the box. Therefore, `overflow: hidden` is not an option

Comment: you need only the vertical scroll in that case? or both horizontal and vertical?

Comment: @Roysh In this particular case I need only the vertical one. However, it can be that the width of `.inner` is `500`, and in this case I would need both.

Comment: last try: 
https://jsfiddle.net/w053kLkw/9/

Comment: @Roysh This is actually crops out a chunk of image at the right border - not the desired result. But thanks anyway for the persistence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible in CSS AFAIK (you need JS or you should not use floats!).

When you `float` an item, it is removed from the normal `block formatting context`. Floated items won't respect `max-width` as it will shrink to its content- so specifying a `width` to `outer` would be needed.

See what happens below when I set `width: 400px` also.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.outer {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}
.inner {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<span>Text here</span>
</body>
```

**Explanation**:

According to W3C specs, a width should always be specified to floated elements (other than `replaced elements` like image which has an implicit width). Otherwise we will see unpredictable behaviour.

See the section: *Do floated items need a width?* in this [link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm).

> If no width is set, the results can be unpredictable. Theoretically, a
>   floated element with an undefined width should shrink to the widest
>   element within it. This could be a word, a sentence or even a single
>   character - and results can vary from browser to browser.

This means `outer` will take the width of the `inner`- and as `overflow` is not `visible` the browser behaves as it sees fit.

Comment: This does not answer my question. The result of your code is not the desired result. In addition, `max-width` has nothing to do with the problem described.

Comment: @Roman AFAIK you can't solve it in pure css unless you are comfortable with `overflow: hidden` or you use JS here

Comment: This may be in fact so. I was thinking about solution for quite a while and could not come up with anything. Therefore, I wanted to ask, if someone else can. If it is impossible, I will go for JS.

Comment: Edit your answer to state the impossibility of achieving this and I will upvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122415/discussion-between-roman-and-kukkuz).

Comment: @Roman got time only now to explain it further- have added in the details, let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: I think, you are right that it is impossible to do with CSS. However, I do not think that the reason is in floating. I tried this in different combinations and came to conclusion that the rendering of scroll bars is up to the browser and it is impossible to interfere with this process through CSS or even JS (at least in a nice and simple way).